# Update spreadsheets cell value by Using Google > Sheets API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

## Overview

- I have inserted order data into a spreadsheet through spureadsheets api.
- After that, I need to update the order data once inserted in the spreadsheet so that the customer can transfer the fee and the administration can process the shipment.
- I would like to get the cell range where the updated order data exists and update the values in the corresponding cell range.
- Can someone please help me with this?

### The problem that is happening

- Here I want to insert the following data into the range A5 to G5 on my spreadsheet. => (Wednesday, 12004, paid, 2021-11-05, jolly, 0145)
- However, I want to get the cell range A5-G5, which is the cell position where the updated order data exists, but I don't know how to get the cell range using the API.

### Processing test that I did

- I was not able to get the cell location where the updated order data was located, so I tried to test by passing the range I wanted to update directly to the $range variable. However, it did not update correctly in the cell position A5-G5 where the updated order data was located.

```php
1.$range = $sheet_ym.'!A1:""'; //I specified column A1 and an empty string, but got an error message.
```

```php
2. $range = $sheet_ym.''; //No column and only an empty string forced the top row to be overwritten instead of the row with the updated order.
```

```php
3. $range = $sheet_ym.'; !A1:A1000 //I got an error message when I specified column A1 + row A1000 => "Requested writing within range ['202112'!A1:A1000], but tried writing to column [B]" ["domain"]=> string(6) "global" ["reason"]=> string(10) "badRequest' }
```

```php
4. $range = $sheet_ym.'!A1:O1000'; //Specifying A1 and O1000 forced the top row to be overwritten instead of the row where the updated order exists.
```

### What I need support for.

- Can you please tell me how to get the position of the cell where the updated order data exists, or how to specify a value for $range and automatically update the data in the appropriate cell range according to the updated order data
- Every time I confirm a payment or complete a dispatch on the application side, the function insertif in the source code is triggered and the order data is inserted into the spreadsheet.
  If I find duplicate values in the order_id, I want to overwrite the cell data in the row where the duplicate data exists. (I am unable to implement this correctly.)
- In the sample you can see what happens when the data in the row with an order_id of 12004 (in the range A5 - G5) is updated.
  When the payment is confirmed, the values C5 and D5 are updated.
  When the payment is confirmed and the shipment is completed, the value of E5 is updated.
- If no duplicate values are found in the order_id, then the data will be added to the last row in the spreadsheet. (I've already implemented this and it works fine.)

### The state of the spreadsheet before the payment confirmation on the application side

- sheet name = 202111
- (order_id = 12004)

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | week | order_id | is_paid | paid_day | send | name | account_id |
| 2 | Monday | 12001 |  |  |  | mercy | 0123 |
| 3 | Monday | 12002 | paid | 2021-11-02 | send | kate | 0153 |
| 4 | Tuesday | 12003 | paid | 2021-11-5 |  | tarkey | 0097 |
| 5 | Wednesday | 12004 |  |  |  | jolly | 0145 |
| 6 | Thursday | 12005 | paid | 2021-11-06 | send | rashford | 0083 |

### The state of the spreadsheet when the payment has been confirmed on the application side, but the shipment has not been processed

- sheet name = 202111
- (order_id = 12004)

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | week | order_id | is_paid | paid_day | send | name | account_id |
| 2 | Monday | 12001 |  |  |  | mercy | 0123 |
| 3 | Monday | 12002 | paid | 2021-11-02 | send | kate | 0153 |
| 4 | Tuesday | 12003 | paid | 2021-11-5 |  | tarkey | 0097 |
| 5 | Wednesday | 12004 | paid | 2021-11-6 |  | jolly | 0145 |
| 6 | Thursday | 12005 | paid | 2021-11-06 | send | rashford | 0083 |

### The state of the spreadsheet when both payment confirmation and dispatch processing are done on the application side

- sheet name = 202111
- (order_id = 12004)

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | week | order_id | is_paid | paid_day | send | name | account_id |
| 2 | Monday | 12001 |  |  |  | mercy | 0123 |
| 3 | Monday | 12002 | paid | 2021-11-02 | send | kate | 0153 |
| 4 | Tuesday | 12003 | paid | 2021-11-5 |  | tarkey | 0097 |
| 5 | Wednesday | 12004 | paid | 2021-11-6 | send | jolly | 0145 |
| 6 | Thursday | 12005 | paid | 2021-11-06 | send | rashford | 0083 |

### SourceCode

```php
function　api_insertif($sheet_name=NULL,$current_date=NULL,$where=NULL,$input_data=array()){
$sheet_name=isset($sheet_name)?$sheet_name:'monthly';
$current_date=isset($current_date)?$current_date:date('Y-m-d');
$where=isset($where)?$where:'';
//The $input_data contains the customer order information.
$input_data=isset($input_data)?$input_data:array();
//A flag to separate insert and update operations on the spreadsheet
$insert=false;

//Set the new insertion flag to true
$insert = true;

//Sheet name (taken from the current year, e.g. 202110,202111)
$sheet_ym=isset($sheet_ym)?$sheet_ym:date('Ym');

//Receipt number of the order customer is trying to confirm
$duplicate_check_id = $input_data[0]['orderid'];

//Extracting order information from the worksheet
$worksheet_order_val = $worksheet['values'];

//Check that there are no duplicate orderids in the worksheet.￥￥
foreach($worksheet_order_val as $sheet_val){

　if($sheet_val[2] == $duplicate_check_id){

    var_dump('There is a duplicate order ID.');

　　   $insert = false;

　}

}

var_dump('The insertion or update process has been checked.');

//If it is a new order and not an update of the order data
if($insert){

  
//The $inputdata contains the data of the order when the order is actually placed or when the management confirms the payment.
foreach($input_data as $row_data){

//Exception handling starts
try{

$client = $this->google_client;
$service = new  Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = 'myspreadsheetid';
//202109, 202110, 202111, etc. The year and month are used as the sheet name.
$sheet_ym=isset($sheet_ym)?$sheet_ym:date('Ym');
$range = $sheet_ym.'!$A1';
$option = [
'valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'
];

$requestBody = new  Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([

'values' => [

[　　
$row_data['week'],
$row_data['order_id'],
$row_data['is_paid'],
$row_data['paid_day'],
$row_data['send'],
$row_data['name'],
$row_data['account_id']
]
],

//Inserting new order data into a spreadsheet
$service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $requestBody,$option);

var_dump('Order number has been successfully completed and inserted');

}catch(Exception  $e){

 //Handling data insertion failures
 var_dump('function api_insertif() : Failed to insert some data');
 var_dump($e);

 return  false;
 }
}
//===============================================================================
//From here on down is not an insertion, but a process to update the spreadsheets
//===============================================================================
}else{
    
    
    foreach($input_data as $row_data){

    　　　　　　　//Exception handling starts
    　　　　　　　try{
    　　　　　　 　　var_dump('The same order number as the current order exists in the     spreadsheet, so update it.')
    　　　　　　 　　
    　　　　　　 　　$client = $this->google_client;　
　　　　　　　　　　　
    　　　　　　　　　　$service = new  Google_Service_Sheets($client);

    　　　　　　　　　　$spreadsheetId = 'myspreadsheetid';
     
         $option_1 = [
    　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　'valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'
         ];
         $option_2 = 'USER_ENTERED';
        
        //Define the RequestBody
         $updateBody = new  Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([

         'values' => [
                    [
                        $row_data['week'],
                        $row_data['order_id'],
                        $row_data['is_paid'],
                        $row_data['paid_day'],
                        $row_data['send'],
                        $row_data['name'],
                        $row_data['account_id']
                     ]
                ],
            ]);

    //Update process
    $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $updateBody,      $option_1);

    var_dump('The insertif update process is now complete.');
  
}catch(Exception  $e){

    var_dump('The update process of insertif could not be performed.');
    var_dump($e);
    exit;

return  false;

}

}


}
```

### Libraries and external services used

- google-api-php-client--PHP5.6  v2.11.0
  https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases
- Google Cloud Platform
  https://console.cloud.google.com/

### The page I am referring to

- php google api client
  https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client
- Migrate from Sheets API  from  v3 https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#v4-api_5
- PHP QuickStart
  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your question. In order to correctly understand it, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images?

Comment: I did not explain myself well. Sorry,
I added some explanations to the "What I need support for..." section and showed what the spreadsheet looked like when I processed the payment and dispatch of the order data on the application side.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. And I couldn't understand the sample input and output situations. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.